How to change the Opacity of a Graphics3D but not at the Plot3D (or whatever underlying) level?
I'm trying to write a function that takes a Graphics3D—ideally any type but for now just a Plot3D—and creates 2 slightly modified versions—namely changes to color, viewing angle, and opacity. However I'm having difficulty with the Opacity part, getting errors like

Graphics3DBox is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.

Here's a simplified, minimal example to reproduce my scenario, removing the function definition and other details:
plot = Plot3D[
   Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -1, 2},
   Mesh -> None,
   Axes -> None,
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Default]
   ];
plot1 = plot /. _Directive -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
plot2 = plot /. _Directive -> Directive[RGBColor[0, 1, 1]]
RotateGraphics3D[graphic_, degrees_] :=
  Graphics3D[
   GeometricTransformation[graphic[[1]],
    RotationTransform[degrees Degree, {0, 0, 1}]
    ]];
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], RotateGraphics3D[plot1, -5]}],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], RotateGraphics3D[plot2, 5]}]
 ]

I read that the particular error I presented may point to my wrapping a Graphics3D in another Graphics3D. I tried several other permutations of Show and Graphics3D and Opacity—even tried a replacement strategy mentioned by @MrWizard in a comment to this question:
plot /. _Directive :> Opacity[.5, Red]

In some way I got that to work, but it was affecting the GraphicsComplex underneath, and there's actually an issue with this that's important to my problem: I do not want the Opacity to be applied to the plot. The reason is, when doing so, parts where you see the surface through another part of the surface create composite shades. What I actually need is the opaque image as-is, only turned partially transparent, as if merely posting a screenshot of the image and turning down its opacity.
I know one way to do this is via Image. However using Image appears to take away the ability to generate an interactive (e.g. mouse-rotatable) entity in the end, I'm guessing because it's not a Graphics3D anymore. My aim is to keep the final result interactive. How can I preserve Graphics3D but change its Opacity but not at the Plot3D level?

Edit: @MichaelE2 partially achieved what I was aiming to do, but using his result I can point out a nuance I was having difficulty explaining:

In the region circled red, notice the background part of the blue surface is visible through the foreground part of the blue surface. This would not happen if the surface were truly opaque (and in its opaque form, turned down in opacity). So that's what I meant by wanting to change opacity of not the 3D surface itself, but the, I guess, projection of it to our eyes.
Note however that it's okay and desired for the red and blue surfaces to be seen through each other. These strangely specific requirements are necessary to create an effective 3D illusion through red-blue glasses. There is another question on this site about creating anaglyphs, but the  solutions there more or less rasterize the Graphics3D into an Image, taking away interactivity. I am trying to preserve the Graphics3D-ness of the result.

You correctly surmised that nested Graphics3Ds is the problem. Did you try Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], First@RotateGraphics3D[plot1, -5]}],   Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], First@RotateGraphics3D[plot2, 5]}]]?

I don't see how plot /. _Directive :> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]] affects the graphics complex. It removes the default specularity and default lighting, but I don't think it changes the complex.

If I understood, maybe you want this:
Show[RotateGraphics3D[plot1, -5] /. 
  Graphics3D[g_, rest___] :> Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], g}, rest],
 RotateGraphics3D[plot2, 5] /. 
  Graphics3D[g_, rest___] :> Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], g}, rest]]


You can try playing with "DepthPeelingLayers" (see for instance, this answer). Again, I'm uncertain I've understood exactly what is desired:
Show[RotateGraphics3D[plot1, -5] /. 
  Graphics3D[g_, rest___] :> Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], g}, rest],
 RotateGraphics3D[plot2, 5] /. 
  Graphics3D[g_, rest___] :> Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], g}, rest],
 BaseStyle -> RenderingOptions -> {"DepthPeelingLayers" -> 2}
 ]


Check the top left-center: The surface can be seen through itself. I think you want each surface to be opaque to itself but translucent to the other one. That may not be possible with the way 3D graphics work.

Hi Michael, thanks for taking a look. I edited my question with a copy of your image to explain a certain nuance. Regardless, I may learn something from your answer to try some new things.

Interesting approach with "DepthPeelingLayers"! Where my red circle was it indeed looks correct. So yes, I'm not sure why that didn't work in the top left-center as you point out. I'll play around with that, thank you.

@AndrewCheong I think it didn't work because all polygons are treated as independent. So if 2 polygons overlap in the projection above, the one in back shows through the one in front. It doesn't matter what color they are or how they were generated. I think that is also happening in the spot you circled, but the 3rd sheet behind the fold in the cyan surface does not show through because the depth is limited to 2 layers. I think "DepthPeelingLayers" does something similar to what you want, but it does not do exactly what you want.
